Finiteness of an integral
In a paper I am reading, the following seems to be claimed:
Let $f:[0,\infty)\to [2,\infty)$ be a continuous, monotonically increasing function with $\lim_{x\to\infty}f(x)=\infty$ and let $\alpha>3/2$.
Is it true that
$$
\int_0^\infty \frac{f(x+1)-f(x)}{f(x+1)\big(\log(f(x))\big)^\alpha}dx
$$
is finite?
The condition on $\alpha$ stems from other appearances of $\alpha$, so I think that $\alpha>1$ should do. Maybe that continuity of $f$ is superfluous, too.

I think it is at least very plausible: If you assume that $f$ is differentiable, and replace $(f(x+1)-f(x))/f(x+1)$ with the approximation $f'(x)/f(x)$, then the function in the integral is (up to a nonzero constant factor) the derivative of $(\log(f(x))^{-\alpha+1}$ which converges to $0$ if $\alpha>1$. I believe this heuristics can be made rigorous (using some kind of Abel summation).

The answer is yes. Indeed, let $a:=\alpha>1$ and $g:=\ln f$. Then the integral in question is
$$I:=\int_0^\infty dx\,\frac{1-e^{-(g(x+1)-g(x))}}{g(x)^a}
\le\int_0^\infty dx\,\frac{\min(1,g(x+1)-g(x))}{g(x)^a} \\
\le\int_0^1 \sum_{n\ge0}\frac{h_n}{s_{n-1}^a},$$
where
$$h_n(x):=\min(1,g(x+n+1)-g(x+n)),\quad s_n:=g(0)+\sum_{k=0}^n h_k.$$
For $n=0,1,\dots$ we have $s_{n-1}\ge g(0)>0$, so that
$$s_n=s_{n-1}+h_n\le s_{n-1}+1\le Cs_{n-1}$$
for $C:=1+1/g(0)$. So,
$$I\le C^a\int_0^1 \sum_{n\ge0}\frac{h_n}{s_n^a}
\le C^a\int_0^1 \sum_{n\ge0}\int_{s_{n-1}}^{s_n}\frac{ds}{s^a} \\
\le C^a\int_0^1\int_{s_{-1}}^\infty\frac{ds}{s^a}
=C^a\int_0^1\int_{g(0)}^\infty\frac{ds}{s^a}<\infty.\quad\Box$$

The idea to introduce sequence $s_n$ which bounds $g$ from below is quite nice, I was just about planning to write a much uglier proof.

@AlekseiKulikov : thank you for your kind comment.

Why the downvote??

Or you may integrate over the large interval $[0,N]$ a pointwise bound
$$
\frac{e^b-e^a}{e^b a^{\alpha}} \leqslant 
C(\alpha)\cdot (a^{1-\alpha}-b^{1-\alpha}) \tag{$\heartsuit$} 
$$
for $a=\log f(x)$, $b=\log f(x+1)$, the integral of RHS is uniformly bounded due to cancellation.
To prove ($\heartsuit$), note that $(e^b-e^a)/e^b=1-e^{a-b}\leqslant \min (1,b-a)$ and consider two cases:
if $b\leqslant 2a$, use Lagrange theorem $a^{1-\alpha}-b^{1-\alpha}=(-1+\alpha)(b-a)c^{-\alpha}$ for some $c$ between $a$ and $b$, so, $c\leqslant 2a$;
if $b>2a$, then simply $a^{1-\alpha}-b^{1-\alpha}\geqslant (1-2^{1-\alpha})a^{1-\alpha}$.
